# how to change the display items of a dynamically created combo box according to the text selected from other box

Tags: c#, windows, forms

while making my project on C#(win-form),i have stuck on a problem ,i have to dynamically generate 2 combo box on each click of add button (button1) ,,and side by side i have to bound the second combo box with the index change of the first box,,data is retrieved from the database(sql server).this is my code please help

```
    int _i = 0;int p = 0; int x=2; int y=0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = p; i < x; i++)
        {  ComboBox C1 = new ComboBox();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from company ",con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "Company");
            C1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Company"];
            C1.DisplayMember = "Company_Name";
            con.Close();

            C1.Location = new Point(160 + x, 30 * p + 10); ;
            C1.Name = "Combo - " + p;
            C1.Parent = this;

            p++;



        }

        x = x + 2;
        y++;
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on `bound the second combo box with the index change of the first box`? How do you want to bind them?

Comment: yes sure ,actually i want that when i select any of the text from the first combo box then the text from the second combo box should change accordingly as in the database

Comment: like if i have company xyz in combox 1 in database and it relates to sub branch abc then ,,,while selecting xyz from 1st automatically 2nd should display abc...i want to bind them through a table from database

Comment: Your code doesn't show any connection between the 2 DataSources of your comboboxes. We have to know the connection (for example some `Branch Id in the first combo) matches with the same in the second combo).

Comment: yes, i know ,,just now i have only connected a single data source for both the comboboxex,because i am unable to fix the logic that how can i connect two comboboxex with each other when the are created dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question just if in case anyone else is facing the same problem--

While creating combobox attach the selectedIndexChanged event handler with it -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c1 = new ComboBox();
        Point loc1 = new Point(50, 80);
         Point loc2 = new Point(250, 80);
        c1.Name = "combobox1";              
        c1.Items.Add("ABC");
        c1.Items.Add("XYZ");
        c1.Items.Add("PQR");
        c1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(combobox1__SelectedIndexChanged);
        c1.Location = loc1;

        ComboBox c2 = new ComboBox();
        c2.Name = "combobox2";
        c2.Location = loc2;

        this.Controls.Add(c1);
        this.Controls.Add(c2);
    }

    private void combobox1__SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox dummy = sender as ComboBox;
        if(dummy.SelectedItem == "ABC")
        ((ComboBox)dummy.Parent.Controls["combobox2"]).Items.Add("Your Intended items");


    }
```